# How to pass parameters from a batch file to another as strings

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So the title may not be very explicit about what I'm looking for, but basically I have this code:

```
echo python %2 "%1" >> activate_wrapper.bat
```

This code is inside a .bat file and it's purpose is to build another .bat file that will run a python script. Thing is I don't want to write the value of %1 to activate_wrapper.bat, I want to write the string "%1".

**Expected line in activate_wrapper.bat:**

```
python secondArg %1
```

**What am I getting:**

```
python secondArg "firstArg"
```

Thanks in advance guys.

**SOLUTION:**

```
echo python %2 %%1 >> activate_wrapper.bat
```

Comment: Have you tried %%1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computer cannot read your mind, it doesn't know you only want to expand one of the parameters!

You must escape the `%` to prevent expansion:

```
echo hello %2 "%%1" >> temp.txt
set something=whatever
echo hello %%something%% >> temp.txt
```